# Documentation for unmentioned functions and types in llvm?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am struggling to learn llvm programming from programmer's manual: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#introduction

(1) In the following code:

```
Function &Func = ...
for (BasicBlock &BB : Func)
  errs() << "Basic block (name=" << BB.getName() << ") has " << BB.size() << " instructions.\n";
```

The function BB.getname() is not mentioned as a public memeber function of class BasicBlock in the link: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html . Where can I see it's documentation?

(2) In the following code:

```
td::set<Instruction*> worklist;  
for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I)
  worklist.insert(&*I);
```

The functions inst_begin(), inst_end() are not class member functions (as they have no F.inst_begin()) and the type inst_iterator is not a member type of any class - so where can I find the documentation for such functions and types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is actually mentioned on that page as a member inherited from `llvm::Value`, but it's only visible if you expand the "Public Member Functions inherited from `llvm::Value` section".

   So when you're looking for a member of a class and you don't see it, try expanding all the lists of inherited members and search again.
2. It's a member of the `llvm` namespace, so you can find it on [that namespace's documentation page](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#a49a219f3fe3d7a6cc07c49a1ea766d6d). There's also an alphabetical index of all namespaces' members, which you can access by selecting "Namespaces -> Namespace Members" in the top menu and then selecting the appropriate letter.